# Openlayers 3 screws up rendering of vector data on high zoom

Tags: openlayers, vector-layer

I'm working on a web app that needs to show a lot of detail.

It's also loading a geoJSON file as background, but I have problems with it when zooming in. It's like the vector renderer doesn't find the off-screen point, and just renders some horizontal line.

See the two images, where the first is zoomed in to the deepest level, and the second is zoomed out one level (so shows the features correctly).

I've tried to enlarge the render buffer of the vector layer, but to no avail, even not with crazy values like 20000 (instead of the default 100).

Does anyone have an idea on how to let OL3 find the off-screen point without changing the maximum zoom level? Preferably also without changing the geoJSON but perhaps a specification of how far points on a line may be apart might work.

[image: Zoomed in to the deepest level]
[image: Zoomed out one level]